# SSRS Report how to sum field has IF condition

Tags: reporting-services

1. I am learning ssrs reporting and dashboard.
2. I have a requirement, i am having Field 1 and Field 2 in my report which is having if condition inside and get the values.
3. I need to have Field 3 (total of Field 1 records) Field 4 (total value of Field 2 records), How can i calculate the total records value and display it in field 3 and Field 4?

Field 1   Field 2    Field 3    Field 4

10         30
20         40

I need to use Field 3 and Field 4 in my dashboard and calculate the percentage

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: why not do all of those calculations in your dataset? Leave SSRS only to reset the data and minimise manipulation or calculation in the front end..

Comment: you can use the sum function to surround the expression used on the data region to get the result dor the sum row

Answer (score 0):

do you expect something like below?? I am not sure If I understand your req correctly.
In my case I have added extra column Field3 and this will hold sum of amount. 
[image]

Is this what you want??. If yes then

[image]